# Npgsql работа с курсором

Tags: c#

Как организовать просмотр по 100 записей из таблицы с помощью npgsql. При просмотре хотелось бы ходить по курсору т.е получать новые 100 записей и при желании к предыдущим 100?

Comment: Собираетесь всё это время, пока пользователь просматривает записи держать соединение открытым?

Comment: Уже придумал как без курсоров рекурсивно обходить свою структуру , соединение создаю теперь при запросе следующих  записей))

Comment: Отлично, напишите ответ!